# Reset Salesforce Datetime field via AMPsript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to reset a Salesforce Datetime field to empty, I just receive an Error 500.

Both

```
SET @dateTimeField = UPDATESINGLESALESFORCEOBJECT("Lead", @LeadId,@Field, "")
```

or

```
SET @dateTimeField = UPDATESINGLESALESFORCEOBJECT("Lead", @LeadId,@Field, NULL)
```

Doesn't seem to work, ending in an error 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done, because the date value parameter passed in the **[UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm)** function must be a string in a valid ISO format.  An empty string or null value would be invalid.

I've worked around this by setting the date value to some passed date  (ex: `1900-01-01`).  If you still need to have the field set back to null, you can create a workflow in Sales Cloud to set `1900-01-01` values to null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fieldsToNull` property to address this.

If the field value to update is empty, the existing field value will remain unchanged on the Salesforce record object. However, you can include a fieldsToNull property as a function argument to reset one or more field values to null.

**Example:**

```
SET @dateTimeField = UPDATESINGLESALESFORCEOBJECT("Lead", @LeadId, @Field, 'fieldsToNull')
```